# Extract indivudual tweets from a textfile with no line breaks using Python

Tags: python-2.7, twitter

I am trying to read tweets from a text file from a URL

```
http://rasinsrv07.cstcis.cti.depaul.edu/CSC455/assignment5.txt
```

Tweets in the file are listed in a single line (there are no line breaks) and punctuated by “EndOfTweet” string. 
I am reading the file using the following code:

```
import urllib2
wfd = urllib2.urlopen('http://rasinsrv07.cstcis.cti.depaul.edu/CSC455/assignment5.txt')
data = wfd.read()
```

I understand that I have to use split on "EndOfTweet" in order to seperate the lines, but since there is only one line, I do not understand how to loop through the file and separate each line.

```
for line in data:
    line = data.split('EndOfTweet')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close!

by the time you've called `wfd.read()`, `data` will contain the raw text of that file. The normal way to loop over a file is to call something like `for line in data`, which is just looking for newlines to split the data on. In this case, your data doesn't contain the normal newline terminator. Instead, he's using the text `EndOfTweet` to separate your lines. Here's what you should have done:

```
import urllib2
import json
wfd = urllib2.urlopen('http://rasinsrv07.cstcis.cti.depaul.edu/CSC455/assignment5.txt')
data = wfd.read()
for line in data.split('EndOfTweet'):
    # From here, line will contain a single tweet. It appears this line is a JSON parsable structure.
    decoded_line = json.loads(line)
    # Now, lets print out the text of the tweet to show we can
    print decoded_line.get(u'text')
```